# View Image Cropper thumbnail in Umbraco 9

Tags: umbraco

In Umbraco 8 the following code worked:

```
@using Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.ValueConverters;
@{
    Layout = "Main.cshtml";

    var imgCropper = item.Value<ImageCropperValue>("homeImage");
    var thumbUrl = imgCropper.Src + img.Cropper.GetCropUrl("Thumb");
}
```

In Umbraco 9 it gives me

> The type or namespace name 'PropertyEditors' does not exist in the
> namespace 'Umbraco.Core'

This line from [up to date documentation](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Fundamentals/Backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/image-cropper/#sample-code) does not work too:

```
<img src="@Url.GetCropUrl(Model.HomeImage, "thumb", true)" />
```

Giving me

> 'IUrlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'GetCropUrl' and the
> best extension method overload
> 'FriendlyImageCropperTemplateExtensions.GetCropUrl(IPublishedContent,
> ImageCropperValue, string, UrlMode)' requires a receiver of type
> 'IPublishedContent'

What is the correct way to display a thumbnail from image cropper in Umbraco 9 if image cropper fields is named 'homeImage' and it has a thumbnail named 'thumb'?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution 2 minutes after posting the question (d'oh). The command must be as follows:

```
<img src="@Url.GetCropUrl(Model.HomeImage, "thumb")" />
```

Please note there is no last parameter (true), that's what caused the problem.